# Did someone managed to use the Android ID attestation

Tags: android, security, android-keystore, hardware-id, key-attestation

I am testing the android Key & Id attestation on several devices (phones & latest chromecast) with that sample code : https://github.com/vvb2060/KeyAttestation.

While the Key attestation works (generating a pair of key, getting the attestation and parsing the data, etc.), the ID attestation does not (obtaining the Hardware Identifiers of the device, Serial Number, IMEI, etc.).

Basically, I get the same result as the first answer to this question : [Sample code showing how to use Android ID Attestation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184356/sample-code-showing-how-to-use-android-id-attestation)

From the other answers, I understand that these HW Identifiers must be provisioned to the TEE by the vendor prior the release of the device, which is optional and is confirmed here : https://source.android.com/security/keystore/attestation#hardware-identifiers.
It means that if the device was not provisioned, it won't be possible to get these HW IDs, even if you make your app a system app (necessary condition to access the HW IDs number 2).

So, since the question I cited earlier is 3yrs old and I could not find more about that subject, did someone managed to make this work? With or without a system-app ?

Thx

Comment: What do you mean by attestation?

Comment: @SagarBalyan https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation

Comment: Why do you need this? @kode48

Comment: @SagarBalyan I would like to use use the IMEI or serial number as a unique ID to authenticate the device to my backend